# How do I remove XML elements without removing content from the elements' tail?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to delete nodes in an xml file. I've managed to get that far but when the script runs it appears to take the attributes belonging to the parent element which come after with it.

Here is the code:

```
for i, pid in enumerate(root.findall(".//p")):
   for cont in pid.findall('membercontribution'):
          for col in cont.findall('col'):
                 cont.remove(col)


tree.write('fofo.xml')
```

this:

```
<p id="S6CV0001P0-00507"><member>The Minister for Overseas Development (Mr. Neil Marten)        
</member><membercontribution>: a policy
<col>16</col>
foobar barforb </membercontribution></p>
```

becomes this:

```
<p id="S6CV0001P0-00507"><member>The Minister for Overseas Development (Mr. Neil Marten)    
</member><membercontribution>: a policy </membercontribution></p>
```

How do I code this so that I get to keep the "foobar barforb" part that comes after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What unintentionally gets removed here is not attributes, but the contents of an element's [`tail`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail).

The `tail` property is a peculiarity of the ElementTree API. It is text immediately following an element's end tag and before any other tag. When you remove an element (in this case `col`), you also remove its tail.

The clearest explanation that I have found is this: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pylxml/web/etree-view.html.

---

To get the wanted output, you need to keep a reference to the tail of the removed `col` element and append it to the text of the parent element. A complete example:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

XML = """
<root>
<p id="S6CV0001P0-00507"><member>The Minister for Overseas Development (Mr. Neil Marten)
</member><membercontribution>: a policy
<col>16</col>
foobar barforb </membercontribution></p>
</root>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(XML)

for pid in root.findall(".//p"):
    for cont in pid.findall('membercontribution'):
        for col in cont.findall('col'):
            col_tail = col.tail.strip()          # Get the tail of "col"
            cont.remove(col)                     # Remove "col"
            cont.text = cont.text.strip() + " "  # Replace trailing whitespace with single space
            cont.text = cont.text + col_tail     # Add the tail to "membercontribution"

print ET.tostring(root)
```

Output:

```
<root>
<p id="S6CV0001P0-00507"><member>The Minister for Overseas Development (Mr. Neil Marten)
</member><membercontribution>: a policy foobar barforb</membercontribution></p>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there any way to remove the line break that appears between "policy" and "foobar"?